# Express URIError: Failed to decode param

Tags: node.js, express, url-encoding, next.js

I'm using next.js with a custom express server when the params of a request contains `%` it causes this error:

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '%%faker'
at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
at decode_param (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:172:12)
at Layer.match (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:148:15)
at matchLayer (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:574:18)
at next (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:220:15)
at middleware (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\http-proxy-middleware\lib\index.js:43:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
at D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (D:\ahmed\coding\react js\with-redux-app\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

for example if the request is `http://localhost:3000/summoner/eune/%%faker` the error happens but if it's `http://localhost:3000/summoner/eune/^^faker` the `^^` gets encoded and the url becomes `http://localhost:3000/summoner/eune/%5E%5Efaker` and everything works perfectly.i could fix this error by following this answer [Express handling URIError: Failed to decode param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125216/express-handling-urierror-failed-to-decode-param) like so:

```
server.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err instanceof URIError) {
    err.message = "Failed to decode param: " + req.url;
    err.status = err.statusCode = 400;
    console.log(err);
    return res.redirect(`http://${req.get("Host")}${req.url}`);
    // return app.render(req, res, "/_error");
  }
});
```

`` return res.redirect(`http://${req.get("Host")}${req.url}`); `` this will redirect the user from `http://localhost:3000/summoner/eune/%%faker` to `http://localhost:3000/summoner/eune/%25%25faker` and if i use `return app.render(req, res, "/_error");` it will send the default error page provided by next.js back to user but this is not what i want. I want to handle the `%` like `^`.

so my questions are:

1. why the `%` doesn't get encoded to `%25` and if there is a way to make it happen?
2. who is responsible for encoding the browser or express?
3. what is the best way to handle this error?

I'm using node v8.9.1, express ^4.16.3.
Please, make the answer detailed i'm a beginner developer.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you pointed out, urls are [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and `http://localhost:3000/summoner/eune/%%faker` is just not valid as an url.

When you type an invalid url, most browsers are kind enough to change it to something valid, ex: `http://localhost:3000/test test` is automatically changed to `http://localhost:3000/test%20test`, but it's just a fallback to avoid too many errors.

In your case, `%` is not automatically changed to `%25` because browsers cannot know when to substitute `%` and when to leave it. Ex: when you type `%25%25faker`, should this url be used as is or should it be replaced to `%2525%2525faker` ?

In summary: You must use valid urls at any point in time and not rely on browser kindness.