# Getting suspicious error on Nodejs web app

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting the following error in my Nodejs running app:

`URIError: Failed to decode param '/cgi-bin/.%%%%32%%65/.%%%%32%%65/.%%%%32%%65/.%%%%32%%65/.%%%%32%%65/bin/sh'`

What could be the cause and how to solve it ?

I searched for this error on web but did not found any results on how to solve the problem

Comment: Someone is probing your app for vulnerabilities. That happens on the internet. There's no problem to solve here.

Comment: This is part of life when you have a webserver connected to the internet, there are plenty of scanners active that are trying to find servers with known vulnerabilities. You can typically just ignore them.

Comment: Ok but it crashes my website

Comment: Try to handle the error with a middleware: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36147121/11692562

Comment: Or setup a `WAF` between your server and your client

Comment: What do you mean with "it crashes my website"?

Comment: Thank you a lot @devpolo using your reference solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @devpolo , using the following lines of code, solved my problem:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
var err = null;
try {
    decodeURIComponent(req.path)
}
catch(e) {
    err = e;
}
if (err){
    console.log(err, req.url);
    return res.redirect('/404');    
}
next(); });
```